# How to store data in the wp database from the contact form

Tags: wordpress

I need some solution to store data in the wp database from  the contact form and  manage  incoming messages in the admin dashboard.     Contact Form 7 plugin  is not working with me. 
If it is possible to do so or not? This has me stumped for a while already.

Comment: Setup a database and use some SQL.

Comment: You're gonna have to [develop your own plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

Comment: google `wordpress wpdb`

Comment: You could use contact form 7 and save those with [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/). Doesn't show in the dashboard tough.